# MongoDB in python - Aggregate using $lookup and $out

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, aggregate

I'm currently trying to learn MongoDB but I'm doing it on python. I have 2 sheets of data, I'm working on. [Sample data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ncusRiy1_BpPT5RGihvRuNYAbG41gn2gl34YF7Iw0T8/edit?usp=sharing) . This is not complete data but just part of the data I was working on. The actual data has too many rows.

So as you can see at data, I have a similar column in sheet 1 - Flights and sheet2 - Airlines which is 'OP_UNIQUE_CARRIER'. I wanted to aggregate based on these values and create a new column in the 'flights' collection and also output a new collection called 'newairinfo'. These collections (flights and airlines) are all under db called 'air'.

Here's my code:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pprint

client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
db = client.air
outputOrder = [("DAY_OF_WEEK", pymongo.DESCENDING), ("ARR_DELAY", pymongo.ASCENDING), ("TAIL_NUM", pymongo.DESCENDING), ("AIR_TIME", pymongo.ASCENDING)]

airlinescollection = db.airlines
flightcollection = db.flights
flightcollection.aggregate([
    {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'airlines', 
            'localField': 'OP_UNIQUE_CARRIER', 
            'foreignField': 'OP_UNIQUE_CARRIER', 
            'as': 'airline'
        }
    }, {
        '$out': 'newairinfo'
    }
])

results=flightcollection.find().sort(outputOrder).limit(10)
for result in results:
    print(result)
```

I've tried this code but it always throws empty result at the end. I've tried this code based on the MongoDB documentation for aggregate, $lookup,$out but it's still the same.

Please tell me what I can do to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

`$out` stage does not produce a result, it inserts matching documents into the specified collection.

If you want to retrieve documents from the pipeline, remove `$out` stage.

Comment: But do u think the aggregate $lookup part is fine?

Comment: So if i want to add 'airline' data into 'flights' i should actually be using $out : flight ?

Comment: flightcollection.aggregate([
    {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'airlines', 
            'localField': 'OP_UNIQUE_CARRIER', 
            'foreignField': 'OP_UNIQUE_CARRIER', 
            'as': 'airline'
        }
    }, {
        '$out': 'flightcollection'
    }
])

Comment: If you are trying to get aggregation working at all, remove $out since it's not helping you debug (you have to separately retrieve the results from the destination collection) and debug your aggregation pipeline. Once you have the result set you want, add $out to write it to a collection, if this is what you want.

Comment: Yes. Thats what i want to do. But I'm still learning this. Can you direct me the right way for getting the $lookup,aggregate work. I'm a bit lost and I've been working to debug this since the last 30 hrs. I tried going through examples and replicating the same but that didn't help for some odd reason.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#examples provides examples you can follow. If you are not able to copy-paste them as is into your environment and obtain the results advertised, figure out why first before trying to do something with your own data set.